# React Check in a Array when item is checked

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following method that when when i click an element i make it checked and if the element is checked already i make it unchecked

```
const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);

const handleElementClick = (index) => {
    setElements(prevState => {
        return prevState.map((element, i) => {
            if (i === index) {
                element.checked = !element.checked
            }
        return element
    })})  
}
```

Now i want to create an other method where i am able to create an array of my elements checked

starting from here

```
const [elementsChecked, setElementsChecked] = useState([]);
```

How can i make this check with React Hooks to have an other array of elements checked from the array elements already created?

Comment: does your elements have id?

Comment: They have not @Taghi Khavari

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: I am trying it, i do not understand why you put under the UseEffect, i think i need just an other method

Comment: since your `elementsChecked` are derived from `elements` it would be a more React approach not to create another state to preserve single source of truth, but instead create a variable that is calculated derived from `elements`

Comment: that's because this is the simplest approach. also give you an option that when `elements` state changes you're going to set `elementsChecked` automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to use `useEffect` hook like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(elements.length){
    setElementsChecked(elements.filter(element => element.checked));
  }
}, [elements])
```

Comment: I get close to my solution if i use the setElementsChecked inside the method like this => https://jsfiddle.net/ef436o1g/1/

Comment: @Koala7 In your linked solution `setElementsChecked` will always use the the previous version of `elements`. Calling `setElements` will update `elements` in the next render, not in the current context.

Comment: @Koala7 yep, @3limin4tOr is right , you're one cycle behind if you do that. just use `useEffect` like above

Answer (score 2):

Since your `elementsChecked` are derived from `elements` I would suggest to create a variable calculated from that state instead to preserve single source of truth principle. You could use [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to memorize its value.

```
const elementsChecked = useMemo(() => elements.filter(element => element.checked), [elements])
```